# How to write a RealmList in a node realm schema

Tags: node.js, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-list

I have a schema for OrderEntry which has a RealmList of another realm object ItemEntry:

```
export const OrderEntrySchema: Realm.ObjectSchema = {
 name: 'OrderEntry',
 primaryKey: '_id',
 properties: {
  ...
  items: ???
 }
}

export const ItemEntrySchema: Realm.ObjectSchema = {
 name: 'ItemEntry',
 primaryKey: 'id',
 properties: {
  ...
  }
}
```

How to define item as a `RealmList<ItemEntry>` as can be done in android?

Note: Both schemas are in separate files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a list of ItemEntry like this

```
items: {type: 'list', objectType: 'ItemEntry'}
```

Here is an example with your schemas.

```
const OrderEntrySchema = {
    name: 'OrderEntry',
    primaryKey: 'id',
    properties: {
        id: 'string',
        items: {type: 'list', objectType: 'ItemEntry'}
    }
};

const ItemEntrySchema = {
    name: 'ItemEntry',
    primaryKey: 'id',
    properties: {
        id: 'string'
    }
};
```

If you want to put them in separate files, you will need to import ItemEntry in the file with OrderEntry